# I want the animation to work when i hover on the "a" element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I used bootstrap. Here is my code , I want when `mouseover` an `img` or `a` element to make animation work also when `mouseleave` animation stop.

```css
.progress-bar {
  animation: pr 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes pr {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    color: red;
  }
  10% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  20% {
    background-color: black;
  }
  30% {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  40% {
    background-color: tomato;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: violet;
  }
  60% {
    background-color: rgb(184, 145, 145);
  }
  70% {
    background-color: white;
  }
  80% {
    background-color: rgb(0, 255, 234);
  }
  100% {
    width: 0;
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-top: 50px" data-aos="fade-in" class="choosebybrand">
  <div class="samsung">
    <a href="samsung.html" class="buki">
      <div class="frontimage">
        <img src="images/samsung.png" height="232px" width="115px" alt="">
      </div>
      <h3>Samsung</h3>
    </a>

  </div>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your progress-bar requires an height to be seen.

example:

```css
/* do you need the progressbar to be as wide as the picture box ?*/


/* if yes, uncomment below selector & rule */


/* .choosebybrand {
display:inline-block; 
 }*/

.choosebybrand:hover ~ .progress .progress-bar {
  animation: pr 2s infinite;
  height: 1em;
}

@keyframes pr {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    color: red;
  }
  10% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  20% {
    background-color: black;
  }
  30% {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  40% {
    background-color: tomato;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: violet;
  }
  60% {
    background-color: rgb(184, 145, 145);
  }
  70% {
    background-color: white;
  }
  80% {
    background-color: rgb(0, 255, 234);
  }
  100% {
    width: 0;
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div style="margin-top: 50px" data-aos="fade-in" class="choosebybrand">
  <div class="samsung">
    <a href="samsung.html" class="buki">
      <div class="frontimage">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/150x100&text=samsung" alt="">
      </div>
      <h3>Samsung</h3>
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: im using bootstrap , i also tried that but i dont know why but its not working

Comment: I do not see any bootstrap class here , what is your real code then ? Is it the snippet here not working or what you do with it ?

Comment: the .progress-bar is a bootsrap class , i was using bootsrap at the head of my html code .

Comment: @bleronmexhuani I added bootstrap to the snippet, the animation works when hovering the link

Comment: Thanks man very much

Comment: G-cyrillus if you can remove the link :)

Comment: @bleronmexhuani link removed ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `~` selector.

```css
a:hover ~ .progress-bar {
  animation: pr 2s infinite;
}
```

Comment: thanks but its not working

Comment: Then try using `+` instead of `~`

Comment: its not working

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code **UPDATED**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    @keyframes pr {
        0% {
            width: 0;
            color: red;
        }
        10% {
            background-color: blue;
        }
        20% {
            background-color: black;
        }
        30% {
            background-color: yellow;
        }
        40% {
            background-color: tomato;
        }
        50% {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: violet;
        }
        60% {
            background-color: rgb(184, 145, 145);
        }
        70% {
            background-color: white;
        }
        80% {
            background-color: rgb(0, 255, 234);
        }
        100% {
            width: 0;
            background-color: red;
        }
    }
    .hover-box .progress .progress-bar {
        height: 20px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .hover-box .content:hover + .progress .progress-bar {
        background: red;
        animation: pr 2s infinite;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>

    
    <div class="hover-box">
        <div class="content">
            <a href="#!">Hover me</a>
        </div>
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is the progress-bar ?

Comment: Ok, what's the way the item should animate? the 1st or 2nd

Comment: When the mouse is over the a element , the class .progress-bar should start the animate ,and when the hover is gone , the animation should reset at the beginnig until i hover again over the a element

Comment: Updated code please check

Comment: Why? hover the a element and see

Answer (score 0):

You can't do exactly as required in the question using just CSS as the anchor and img elements are neither parents of the progress bar nor are they siblings. CSS does not allow going 'up' and then down again.

What you can do is sense the hover on an ancestor element of the anchor and img elements which also is a sibling of the progress element and get the animation going on the progress bar then.

```css
.samsung {
  display: inline-block;
}

.samsung:hover~.progress .progress-bar {
  animation: pr 2s infinite;
}

.progress {
  width: 100vw;
}

.progress-bar {
  height: 2px;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: magenta; /* added so something is seen when no hover */
}

@keyframes pr {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    color: red;
  }
  10% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  20% {
    background-color: black;
  }
  30% {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  40% {
    background-color: tomato;
  }
  50% {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: violet;
  }
  60% {
    background-color: rgb(184, 145, 145);
  }
  70% {
    background-color: white;
  }
  80% {
    background-color: rgb(0, 255, 234);
  }
  100% {
    width: 0;
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="margin-top: 50px" data-aos="fade-in" class="choosebybrand">
  <div class="samsung">
    <a href="samsung.html" class="buki">
      <div class="frontimage">
        <img src="images/samsung.png" height="232px" width="115px" alt="">
      </div>
      <h3>Samsung</h3>
    </a>

  </div>
  <div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar"></div>
  </div>
```

Note: the snippet had to add height dimension so the progress bar could be seen.

Comment: I dont know why , but its not working :)

Comment: It is for me (though I had to scroll down to see the progress bar on the small snippet screen). What browser/OS are you using. I have tested on Edge/Chrome Windows10.

Comment: Im using google chrome .

Comment: What are you seeing? Have you tried the snippet full page? Where are you hovering?

Comment: Im hovering over the samsung div ,over the a element , but the animation its just not starting

Comment: Are you seeing anything below the Samsung word?

Comment: I've made the progress bar a magenta colored line when not hovered just so we can be sure we are seeing the same thing,